# How to automatically break my table in PPT before reaching the footer

Tags: powerpoint, footer

I created a table in the power point.

I programmatically put data on the table.

I'm expecting my table to continue on the other page before it reaches the footer.

On my part it overlaps. How can I avoid this?

Comment: PowerPoint won't automatically break your table and continue on the next slide. Instead, you'll probably want to add a row of data at a time, check the .Top+.Height property of the table to determine if it's getting close to the footer and if so, add a new slide, add a table to it and continue adding data to the new table.

Comment: On second thought, when the table reaches the limit, duplicate the slide, delete all but the first row of the table, then start adding your data back. That way you start with a pre-made/pre-formatted slide with a pre-made table in place.